# Mercure publish : Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for

Tags: mercure

I am trying to configure the latest version of Mercure in production mode.

I am running this version mercure_0.10.3_Linux_x86_64

Running command

```
PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY=XXXXXX \
SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY=XXXXXX \
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=* \
ADDR=':3000' \
CERT_FILE=/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt \
KEY_FILE=/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key \
DEBUG=1 \
ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1 \
./mercure

INFO[0000] Mercure started                               addr=":3000" protocol=https
```

Nginx reverse proxy configuration

```
server {
  #listen 80 http2;
  listen 80 ;
  #listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen 443 ssl ;
  ssl on;
  server_name my-domain.com;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
 
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:3000;
        proxy_read_timeout 24h;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
 
    }
}
```

When I try to publish from (https) `https://my-domain.com/.well-known/mercure`, I got the error this error

```
Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates for "https://my-domain.com/.well-known/mercure
```

When I try to publish from (http) `http://my-domain.com/.well-known/mercure`, there is no problem

```
INFO[0022] Update published                              event_id="urn:uuid:6f2ee286-ad54-48c6-b803-c8d7d9d9624c" event_retry=0 event_type= remote_addr="127.0.0.1:50444" update_data="XXXXX" update_private=false update_topics="[/notification/3702778]"
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Sep/2020:16:35:16 +0200] "POST /.well-known/mercure HTTP/1.1" 200 45 "" "Symfony HttpClient/Curl"
```

There is something wrong in my configuration ?

Comment: I've resolved my problem by using Guzzle Http Client to publish with ['verify' => false]

Comment: Can you give more explanation of you solutions ?

Comment: I think open_ssl doest has the certificate for verify, so I disabled verification for Guzzle